# Application of the fundamental theorem of calculus. $F(x)=\int_a^x f(t)(x-t) dt$ evaluate $F''(x)$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Let $f$ be a continuous function on $\Bbb R$

$F(x)=\int_a^x f(t)(x-t) dt$

Evaluate $F''(x)$

I used the fundamental theorem of calculus to attempt this question.

My attempt at the question

$F(x)=\int_a^x f(t)(x) dt-\int_a^x f(t)(t) dt$

$F'(x)=f(x)(x)-f(x)(x)=0$

$F''(x)=?$

However the answer is $f(x)$

Did i use the fundamental theorem of calculus incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by writing $F$ as

$$
F(x) = x\int_a^x f(t)\ dt -\int_a^x t f(t)\ dt.
$$
Now

$$
F'(x) = \int_a^x f(t)\ dt + xf(x) - xf(x) = \int_a^x f(t)\ dt
$$
and then the second derivative is $F''(x) = f(x)$.

Comment: i didn't realize that you could move the $x$ out. was it because it is an integration with respect to t?

Comment: Yep. The variable $x$ acts as a constant with respect to the integration so you can take it out.